# Journey Builder Multiple Entries

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a data extension with more than one entry for a subscriber. These entries are 'Subscriber Key + Enrollment ID' so every entry is unique because one person will enroll to more than one class.

I have set the Contact Entry in my journey to "Re-entry after exit". When the journey is being executed, only one entry enters the journey.

How can I implement this so that every entry in DE enters the journey and being 'Accepted'?

Answer (score 0):

Question for you - did you make the combination of fields the Primary Key in the Data Extension?  Otherwise, you could try writing a query to concatenate the two values into one and write to a new DE.

Finally, assuming you did that - have you set up the appropriate population/attribute groups?  If the record is new to the platform (and assuming combining values would mean a new record), then you must add users to a population first.

Give it a go and let us know

Comment: Hi George, yes I have made the combinations of fields the Primary Key and the population is in place. The issue has been resolved by changing the Journey Entry to 'Re-entry anytime". Previously my setting was 'Re-entry only after existing'.